# access previous rows in python dataframe apply method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column `comp` in a pandas dataframe containing a single column `price`. The value of this new column should be generated by a function that works on the current and last 3 values of the `price`.
`df.apply()` works off a single row, `shift()` doesnt seem to work. Do experts have any suggestion to make it work in a vectorized operation?

Comment: You might want to your attempt with `shift` or `rolling_apply` methods.

Comment: Can you add example? Maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and how Stackoverflow [works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use a series sum [group.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function. Below assumes you have an index or column named ID of increasing row values 1, 2, 3, ... that can be used to count back 3 values.

```
# SERIES SUM FUNCTION
def intsum(x):
    if x < 3:        
        ser = df.price[(df.ID < x)]
    else:
        ser = df.price[(df.ID >= x - 3) & (df.ID < x)]
    return ser.sum()    

# APPLY FUNCTION
df['comp'] = df['ID'].apply(intsum)
```